# Using AWS X-Ray from a different C# class library

Tags: c#, aws-xray

I am trying to integrate AWS X-Ray into one of my application, but I am getting frustrated. I feel that Amazon's documentation is a bit lacking in terms of examples, but hopefully some of you can help me.

My main application is a Web API microservice built in C#. I have a separate client that calls the microservice, and the microservice then communicates with 1) a third party API and 2) some AWS services like DynamoDb and SNS. Furthermore I have built a wrapper library around the AWS services, so instead of calling AWSDynamoDBClient directly, I call it through my wrapper.

On AWS X-Ray console, I can see all incoming and outgoing calls to/from my microservice. However I don't see anything for DynamoDb. If I create the AWSDynamoDBClient directly in my microservice (bypassing the wrapper), then I see all traffic as expected. But once I call it through the wrapper, then nothing happens.

I even tried to inject the `AWSXRayRecorder.Instance` from my microservice into my wrapper, but still nothing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and I'm a bit at a loss at this point.

Any suggestions?

*Edit:*
In my AWS wrapper library, I am doing the following:

`client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
 new AWSSdkTracingHandler(recorder).AddEventHandler(client);`

`recorder` is `AWSXRayRecorder.Instance` being injected from the calling microservice (I'm not sure if this is necessary to pass it along like this, or whether I can just call `AWSXRayRecorder.Instance` directly from the library).

This doesn't work. If I write the same code in the microservice, then it works and I can see the DynamoDb nodes in the X-Ray graph in the AWS console

Answer (score 1):

Can you please describe more about how you are configuring wrapper client with AWS X-Ray.
Usually, following is the way for registration:

`var ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
new AwsSdkTracingHandler(AWSXRayRecorder.Instance).AddEventHandler(client);`

"client" (AmazonDynamoDBClient) needs to be registered. Is the client created, registered with X-Ray and used in the application same?

We (the AWS X-Ray team) are very active on the AWS X-Ray official forum. We're much more likely to quickly respond to future posts if they're made to the [X-Ray specific forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=241&start=0).

Thanks,

Yogi

Comment: Hi Yogi, thanks for the quick reply. I'll post on the X-Ray forum from now on.
I edited my question with a snippet